# Derive minimum length confidence bounds for a F distribution variance ....

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Derive minimum length confidence bounds for a F distribution variance $\sigma^2$
 and the ratio of two F distribution population variances $\frac{\sigma_1^2}{\sigma_2^2}$.

What I got so far is 
$$ P[a < \frac{s_1^2/\sigma_1^2}{s_2^2/\sigma_2^2} < b] $$=$$  P[a < \frac{s_1^2\sigma_2^2}{s_2^2\sigma_1^2} < b]$$ = $$ P[\frac{s_2^2}{s_1^2}a < \frac{\sigma_2^2}{\sigma_1^2} < \frac{s_2^2}{s_1^2}b]$$ = $$ P[\frac{s_1^2}{s_2^2b} < \frac{\sigma_1^2}{\sigma_2^2} < \frac{s_1^2}{s_2^2a}]$$

Is this approach right...How do I move forward with this? Let me know if the question is unclear to you

Comment: Usually, a confidence interval is connected to a certain test statistic. What is your test statistic for $\sigma^2$?

Comment: @Marc: I Have a new post for this question...I have more info there...If you would like to take a look , here is the website http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/763002/help-with-deriving-minimum-length-confidence-bounds-for-a-f-distribution-varianc